# Why question becomes community?

Tags: support, specific-question

Why my question becomes community ? What is it ? The first question in my profile which shows last visiter as community : https://stackoverflow.com/users/227848/harikrishna  Why it has become a community question ?

[Last edited by Community? http://img.skitch.com/20100508-jmqkw2ym1thcdmhta6qkhirai4.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100508-jmqkw2ym1thcdmhta6qkhirai4.png)

Comment: Though yours is not such "CW", see [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow) in [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528898/option-in-the-html-agility-pack-that-parse-from-the-tag-lt-table-lt) isn't community wiki. The community user bumped your question, because there is no upvoted answers, to give it some more attention. Like it's explained in [its profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1):

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep Stack Overflow clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - **Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention**
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

Comment: @S.Mark,Sorry see first question of the link : http://stackoverflow.com/users/227848/harikrishna and what is community wiki ?

Comment: @Harikrishna, looks like one of your question is edited by someone, thats very normal, see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), *Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, ....*

Comment: @S.Mark,But that question is not edited.

Comment: @Harikrishna, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786771) question ?

Comment: @S.Mark,No.The first question listed in my profile( stackoverflow.com/users/227848/harikrishna ) is not edited by anybody.

Comment: could you post that question url, instead of your profile page, because there is 4 different sorting. recent, views, newest, votes, we can't figure out which sorting you have.

Comment: Ah, I've got it, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528898/option-in-the-html-agility-pack-that-parse-from-the-tag-lt-table-lt) one, the community user bumped your question, because there is no upvoted answers.

Comment: @S.Mark,Bumped the answer means ? because no upvoted answer ? Please explain it sir.

Comment: Thanks @Arjan for editing, I was thinking where to search that info, forgot about users/-1's profile. @Harikrishna, please see his edit.